# Cannot acces the database value from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, resultset

I have connected to mySql database from php . I want to fetch details for two columns from it . When I try to access them , it outputs null. 
The same querystring works fine when I run in phpmyAdmin database tool.

Below is my code :

```
$servername = "mysql";
            $username = "$$$$$$$$$";
            $password = "%%%%%%%%%%";
            $databasename = 'blog';

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databasename);

            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } else {
                echo "Connected successfully";
            }



 $select_sql = "Select site_url from sites where id LIKE '%website1Modal%'";
            $result = $conn->query($select_sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
              echo "in if loop";
               echo $result[0];
}
```

The above code does outputs : "Connected successfully" and "in if loop".

Can someone tell me what silly mistake I am doing ?

Comment: You are not in a loop.

Comment: You have to fetch the rows from the result set object ($result in this case) read here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: can't you just read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)? there are examples there, easy to follow, a simple google would solve this `php mysqli fetch`

Comment: @chris85 Thanks. But cant I just hardcode the value and directly try to output $result[0] ? Like I have only 1 row in resultset , a while is not necessarry.

Comment: Than just take out the while. What do you mean `hardcode the value`, the column name changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `if` doesn't put you into a loop. The `if` is a control structure. Use a `while` to enter a loop and put the `fetch` inside so the results are accessible.

Give this a try:

```
$servername = "mysql";
$username = "$$$$$$$$$";
$password = "%%%%%%%%%%";
$databasename = 'blog';
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databasename);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "Connected successfully";
}
$select_sql = "Select site_url from sites where id LIKE '%website1Modal%'";
$result = $conn->query($select_sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "in if control";
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) { //this is optional; if only one row the while can be removed. e.g. $row = $result->fetch_array();
        echo 'in while loop';
        echo $row['site_url'];
    } //if removing while remove this as well
}
```

You can read more about the `if` and `while` controls here.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Here's the manual entry for what [query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) does.

The important bit

> For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object.

and because you have a `mysqli_result object` you need to send that to the [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) which will

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.

Comment: He's fetching 1 (one!) var from the db, putting that in a while loop is unnecessary and makes for messy code.

Comment: @HarriedeLaat how do you know he/she is fetching one row? There is not limit on that query.

Comment: Thanks . 
Adding it into  a while loop worked. 

P.S : echo $row['site_url']; should be change in the code you had posted :)

Comment: @Terminus okay, added a bit more to the end to make the `query` and `fetch` functions clearer how they interact.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch each row of the results using a [`Mysqli_Result::fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

will print each row of the result set.

You can access each property of the result row inside the loop with;

```
$row['col_name'];
```

where `col_name` is the name of a column.

Comment: As I stated in another comment on another answer to this question: He's fetching 1 (one!) var from the db, putting that in a loop is unnecessary and makes for messy code.

Comment: Unnecessary until he want's to read two rows from the database! If there is only one result then there's no additional execution time.

Answer (score -1):

As `$result[0]` is an array, you cannot display it using an `echo` use a `print_r` instead :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result[0]);
echo '</pre>';
```

If you want to display `site_url` var you need to use :

```
echo $result[0]['site_url'];
```

Comment: Forgot to mention,but I have already tried the above options. 
It still doesnt prints the output :(

Comment: Make a `print_r($result);` and post the result in a pastbin

Comment: That is not the issue. If that were an array the OP could echo with `result[0]` if `0` were a key of that array.

Comment: What if `result[0]` is an array ?

Comment: It would output `Array`.

Comment: Okay, it depends of the version of PHP you are using, but in both case, it's easier for debugging to `print_r`

Comment: Actually, the version is irrelevant. It's just that the online editor chris is using is not showing PHP notices. If it was, it would show the one you describe.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but that doesn't help @this.that !

Comment: Hopefully it helps you and chris :)

Comment: That's true :) But we all wanna help this poor @this.that :p

Comment: It would never show an error and the answer here doesn't address the issue the user is encountering. It might throw a notice, if reporting were on. https://3v4l.org/JJNqg

Answer (score -1):

```
// put your db-connection in a different file, preferably placing it outside your webroot
include('../some/folder/dbconn.php');

$select_sql = "Select site_url from sites where id LIKE '%website1Modal%'";
$result = $conn->query($select_sql);

if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
    // fetch the result
    $result = $conn->fetch();
    // echo the result
    echo $result['site_url'];
}

// close db connection
$conn = NULL;
```

Comment: Using a `like` doesn't make sense if OP only wants 1 row. Why not use `=`? This answer will fail to get the OP all their results.

Comment: It is the query from his original question --> I assume he has a reason to do like?

Comment: `$result = $conn->fetch();` is wrong. Should be `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`. You must fetch from the result set object, not the connection.

Comment: Also, setting the `$conn` variable to `NULL` doesn't close the connection; it just loses the connection info. Not that you need to close the connection anyway.